# How to add extra button to WordPress block editor toolbar

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gutenberg-blocks, wp-admin

I want to add an extra button into the block-editor toolbar that shows at the top of the page when editing (using the block editor). It contains the Add Block, Undo, Redo, etc. buttons.
I can see that the buttons are written by JavaScript to a div created in wp-admin/edit-form-blocks.php

Does anyone know of an 'official' way to add a new button or do I just add one in with jQuery?

Many thanks.

Comment: As far as i know there is no official way and is not supported by Gutenberg's API, this will have to be done manually with custom code.

Comment: Answered here on Wordpress Stackexchange : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/355968/add-a-button-to-the-toolbar-of-an-existing-gutenberg-block/356118#356118

Comment: You can find the code and the answers here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/416525/29136. Thanks!